# Two functions with exact same definition gives different results on valgrind. Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c, malloc

## The Problem

I was having some troubles with a library, which makes use of flexible array members. There is no issues to allocate the object, but I can't reliably free it. Whenever the object has to be resized or freed, using free() or realloc(), valgrind outputs errors of reads of uninitialized values, invalid free() calls, etc. I can't share the code, but I've managed to reduce the problematic context to the snippet below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char * rbuff(int len){
    char * ptr = malloc(len);
    return ptr;
}

void cfree(void * b){
    free(*(char**)b);
}

void cbuff(void * b){
    free(*(char**)b);
}

int main(){

    char * g = rbuff(2);
    cbuff(&g);  
    //cfree(&g);

    return 0;
}
```

As it shows, there are two functions with the exact same code to free the object. The original code has lots of functions using free and realloc. All the functions receives and/or returns the object as a void pointer. Reducing it to two as in the snippet, I've observed an interesting undefined behavior. Using the function `cbuff`, the output in valgrind is the following:

```
==6437== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6437== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6437== Using Valgrind-3.19.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6437== Command: ./main
==6437== 
==6437== 
==6437== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6437==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6437==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 2 bytes allocated
==6437== 
==6437== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6437== 
==6437== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==6437== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

There is no problem to free the object. However using `cfree` the output is different, the `free()` call is now invalid:

```
==6716== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6716== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6716== Using Valgrind-3.19.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6716== Command: ./main
==6716== 
==6716== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==6716==    at 0x484447F: cfree (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6716==    by 0x1093E7: main (in /mnt/c/Users/HOME/fd/fbgfbhdbgh/fd/main)
==6716==  Address 0x1ffefffed0 is on thread 1's stack
==6716==  in frame #1, created by main (???:)
==6716== 
==6716== 
==6716== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6716==     in use at exit: 2 bytes in 1 blocks
==6716==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 2 bytes allocated
==6716== 
==6716== 2 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==6716==    at 0x4841888: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6716==    by 0x109370: rbuff (in /mnt/c/Users/HOME/fd/fbgfbhdbgh/fd/main)
==6716==    by 0x1093D7: main (in /mnt/c/Users/HOME/fd/fbgfbhdbgh/fd/main)
==6716== 
==6716== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6716==    definitely lost: 2 bytes in 1 blocks
==6716==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6716==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6716==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6716==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6716== 
==6716== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==6716== 
==6716== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
==6716== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==6716==    at 0x484447F: cfree (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6716==    by 0x1093E7: main (in /mnt/c/Users/HOME/fd/fbgfbhdbgh/fd/main)
==6716==  Address 0x1ffefffed0 is on thread 1's stack
==6716==  in frame #1, created by main (???:)
==6716== 
==6716== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I am not sure of why this is a thing, can someone explain this behavior and give thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: Are you commenting out the `cbuff(&g);` line when removing the comment from the `//cfree(&g);` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cfree` is the name of a [library function in Linux](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cfree.3.html) which is equivalent to `free`.  When you call `cfree` in your code you actually end up calling this library function instead of the one in your code.

If you give this function some other name, the problem goes away.

Comment: So simple, yet such a terrible mistake. I should of checked that. But that is not the problem on the library, as they are not named like that. I will reformulate the question with parts of the  actual code. That was my mistake. Thank you.